# Entity's attribute with multiple values

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database for my website in which, I have a `goal` entity with `frequency` attribute that include `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly`, `yearly` value. Problem is each value has another multiple values represented below

```
goal
  |-- frequency
        |-- daily
             |-- start day
             |-- end day
        |-- weekly
             |-- year
             |-- start week
             |-- end week
        |-- monthly
             |-- year
             |-- start month
             |-- end month
        |-- yearly
             |-- start year
             |-- end year
```

How can I create that database? Can I put `frequency`to a table which reference to 4 another tables or not?
Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you have 2 options:

1)Maintain  1 table called goal and having frequency, year, start, end  columns.
    You will then have all the data in one table.

```
id      frequency      year     start      end
1         daily        null     Monday      Friday
```

2) Having another table called frequency with reference to it in goal table

If you will have 4 tables referencing from goal table you should add 4 foreign keys in goal table and then keeping 4 table, one for each frequency:

```
goal_id    freq_daily_fk   freq_week_fk   freq_month_fk   freq_year_fk

   1            null           2                null           null
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your response, I think I can use 1st method as a separate table called FREQUENCY that referenced with GOAL table

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you want to model goals with different frequencies, and frequency-specific attributes.  This sounds like a supertype-subtype pattern.

You could have a goals table with any common attributes including a frequency indicator:

```
goals (goal_id PK, frequency)
```

and tables for subtype information:

```
daily (goal_id PK/FK, start_day, end_day)
weekly (goal_id PK/FK, year, start_week, end_week)
monthly (goal_id PK/FK, year, start_month, end_month)
yearly (goal_id PK/FK, start_year, end_year)
```

A common requirement with subtyping tables is to enforce mutual exclusivity.  If required, you could do this by including the frequency in each of the subtypes so that a foreign key constraint on (goal_id, frequency) can be specified.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I think it's too many tables to created